# Algorithm to optimize re-assignation of elements in some clusters

Tags: algorithm, optimization, cluster-analysis, matching

This is a pure algorithmic question. I don't know if this problem has a name so let me know if you do.

An algorithm regularly receives elements that must be clustered. At each iteration, it creates a full new set of clusters `C_n+1`. The new set of element is `E_n+1 = E_n + E_new`. Any element of `E_n` has been assigned to a cluster of `C_n` in the previous iteration.

**The problem is to optimize the re-assignation of the clusters in the database.**

For example, if a cluster that had 10 elements at iteration `n`, becomes 2 new elements at `n+1` and is split in two clusters of 8 and 4 elements at this new iteration, we should keep the 8 elements in the cluster and create a new cluster for the 4 remaining elements. **The underlying idea is to preserve at best existing clusters between two iteration.**

Please provide code, generic code or mathematic description to your answer.

**edit:** 
I try to make a clearer explanation: I have a set of elements `E = {e_1, ..., e_n}` and these elements belong to `p` clusters `C_1 = {c_1_1,...c_1_p}` where `c_1_i = {e_7, e_52, e_53...}`. Then I receive some new elements `{e_n+1, ..., e_n+m}` and these elements are clustered (**whatever clustering algorithm it doesn't matter**) in a new set of `q` clusters `C_2 = {c_2_1, ..., c_2_q}` where `c_2_i = {e_7, e_52, e_57...}`. **What algorithm** should I use to **change my clusters `C_1` into clusters `C_2`** without deleting them all and building new one, specifically doing the **minimum of deletion and re-assignation of clusters**

Comment: Where is the problem doing this? Why not preserve all clusters, and only add the new element where it fits best?

Comment: Because adding elements completely change the clustering. In most cases, elements stay together. But as my example describes it (I edited it), new elements can change the distribution and then split or merge clusters.

Comment: Without any constraints or definition regarding addition/deletion/merge of the elements to the existing or new clusters, the problem seem very vague.

Comment: Yes, that is the nature of clustering. So you do not want clustering? But if you only add one element at a time, the changes should be local.

Comment: The constraint is  to preserve at best existing clusters. Otherwise I would simply delete the database of iteration n, and replace it with the clusters of n+1.

Comment: Anony-Mousse, the problem is not about clustering, but how to update a database when you have re-assignations of elements to some groups (previously existing or not).

Comment: The problem description is a bit blurry; what exactly is meant by 'optimizing' the clustering - with respect to what objective? What exactly makes a clustering good or bad?

Comment: See edit. The clustering doesn't matter here. I need to preserve at best the database taking changes of clusters into account.